# using principal component analysis to visualize data

Tags: python, pandas, pca

I am trying to use pca to visualize my data. I have a dataset with 4 variables (date, groundwater level, rainfall, temperature) [Here is an example of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEBZ4.jpg). I want to see if there is a relationship between rainfall and gwl and temp and gwl.

I heard I could try this using pca or regression. I am new to this and a bit confused as to how i can go about doing this.

I followed a tutorial online but in the end i got an error:

```
 >>>> **TypeError: invalid type comparison**.
```

I am confused because the target isn't something simple like 0 or 1 but its the groundwater level (gwl). I am trying to see if there's any correlation between groundwater level and temperature

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Tamarie/Downloads/joined1.xlsx")
print(df.dtypes)
df.head()
df.info()

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
features = ['rainfall', 'temperature', 'Evapotrans']
# Separating out the features
x = df.loc[:, features].values
# Separating out the target
y = df.loc[:,['gwl']].values
# Standardizing the features
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df[['gwl']]], axis = 1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
targets = ['gwl']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['gwl'] == target
    ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 1']
               , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 2']
               , c = color
               , s = 50)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

Comment: Could you give us the type of the variables in the dataframe. So that others can help you.

Comment: Please provide a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Justice_Lords i've edited my question to include an example of my dataset

Comment: Why don't you just use scatter plots? And a correlation matrix heat map? Check out pairplot in seaborn. I don't see why PCA is going to help you here...

Comment: [You should not post code or sample data as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451). Instead, please post in body of question a sample of `joined1.xlsx`.

Comment: @Dan ended up doing this thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
targets = ['gwl']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['gwl'] == target
```

In this line why are you comparing finalDf['gwl'] a list of float with a target a string

Although, if you want to see if there's any correlation between groundwater level and temperature

then you can just plot scatter plot between groundwater level and temperature column

Comment: i ended up using scatter plots because i wasn't at all sure with what i was doing here. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry you will know soon. See, when we have more the 3 feature columns in our data then obviously we cant visualize that, So to visualize data having more then 3 features we use PCA. PCA  transform our columns to 2 or 3 Principal component and then we can visualize those new columns. PCA is a Dimensionality Reduction technique.